# Count checked checkboxes in a DataGridView via Linq

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, checkbox, datagridview

The following code gives me this error: https://prnt.sc/q4truq

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyDataGridView.Columns.Insert(0, new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn());
        MyDataGridView.Rows.Add(4);
        MyDataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = true;
        MyDataGridView.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value = false;
        MyDataGridView.Rows[2].Cells[0].Value = true;
        MyDataGridView.Rows[3].Cells[0].Value = false;
        MyDataGridView.Rows[4].Cells[0].Value = true;

        string strResults = (MyDataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                           .Where(c => Convert.ToBoolean(r.Cells[0].Value).Equals(true))
                           .Count(s => Convert.ToInt32(t.Cells[0].Value))).ToString();
    }
```

Comment: This is easily researched.  What part of the WinForms version are you having trouble with?

Comment: What problem you are facing here? If you want total number of checked checkboxes then you can use Count linq method instead of Sum method.

Comment: `var count = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => Convert.ToBoolean(r.Cells["NameOrIndexOfCheckColumn"].Value)).Count();`

Comment: **@JQSOFT** Thank you very much. Solved.

Comment: Most welcome. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error because already there is no variable named r but there is c so this is your solution my friend ^_^

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyDataGridView.Columns.Insert(0, new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn());
            MyDataGridView.Rows.Add(4);
            MyDataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = true;
            MyDataGridView.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value = false;
            MyDataGridView.Rows[2].Cells[0].Value = true;
            MyDataGridView.Rows[4].Cells[0].Value = true;

            int strResults = MyDataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                           .Where(c => Convert.ToBoolean(c.Cells[0].Value).Equals(true)).ToList().Count;
            MessageBox.Show("" + strResults);
        }
```

Comment: `"" + strResults` ?  Just use `strResults.ToString()`